# Cypher does not use NodeIndexSeek without hint

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I add relationships with an `UNWIND` query (neo4j 3.4.7, 30 GB heap, 30 GB page cache):

```
UNWIND { rels } AS rel
MATCH (a:Locus), (b:Snp)
WHERE a.chr = rel.start_chr AND a.start = rel.start_start AND a.end = rel.start_end AND a.ref = rel.start_ref AND b.sid = rel.end_sid
CREATE (a)-[r:TEST_MAPS]->(b)
SET r = rel.properties
```

Here are example parameters:

```
:param rels => [{start_chr: '6', start_start: 93922926, start_end: 93922926, start_ref: 'h37', end_sid: 'rs782706', properties: {source: 'binder_immuno', uuid: 'e2ee1287-9894-4eb4-8ba8-d8adc4959e50'}}]
```

The properties are indexed with `:Snp(sid)` and `:Locus(chr, start, end, ref)`.

**Problem**: Adding relationships is very slow.

When I create the relationships, the query planner uses a fast `NodeIndexSeek` on `a:Locus` but uses a much slower `NodeIndexScan` on `b:Snp` (at least one order of magnitude slower).

The selection of the planner seems to depend on the Labels which are used, i.e. adding relationships the same way with other labels was fast and used `NodeIndexSeek` only.

I know that I can force the planner to use a seek on `b:Snp`. However, is there a way to tell Cypher to always do a seek when an index is available without changing the query?

Answer (score 1):

Cypher makes no guarantees about how information will be retrieved. The executed plan will vary based on what version of Neo4j (Planner) you are running, and the internal DB statistics at the time of planning.

This is the reason Cypher has [hints](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/using/#query-using) at all. Sometimes the internal statistics will deceive the planner into deciding on a less optimal plan.

One way you **might** be able to get the results you want is to inline property matches where you can. Like doing `MATCH (a:Locus), (b:Snp{sid:rel.end_sid})`. This isn't guaranteed to change the final plan, but moving as much of the WHERE into the MATCH part as you can seems to usually get better plans. (For more complex queries. For simpler ones, there will be no difference. Mileage will vary based on what version of Neo4j you are running.)